# Migrate from serial to identity

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

We have a table in a Postgres 14 DB which id was created using SERIAL and we want to migrate to using IDENTITY instead. That table already has a lot of entries in prod. How can we safely migrate to IDENTITY?

I did some research and found a script that might help, but after testing it, the results were not as I expected...

```
INSERT INTO public.another_table (<columns>) VALUES (<values>);

ALTER TABLE public.another_table
    ALTER COLUMN id DROP DEFAULT;

DROP SEQUENCE public.another_table_id_seq;

ALTER TABLE public.another_table
    ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE INT;

ALTER TABLE public.another_table
    ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO public.another_table (<columns>) VALUES (<values>);
```

If you do something like that, postgres will complain with the following message: `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

Comment: This `ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` is going to add a sequence that starts at 1 which means you will repeating `id`'s when you add new items to the table. You will need to modify the underlying sequence to have its `setval` to be the `max(id)` from the original data. So `select max(id) from public.another_table` then take that number and `select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.another_table'), <the max_id>)`. Then you can do new inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous block to generate the necessary SQL for this. Within that block get the `nevtval` from the current sequence and use that (plus some increment) as the `start with` value for the new generation *sequence_option*. Then drop the sequence after the switch. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/D0wSkePk).

```
do $$
declare 
  l_gen_start text = format('alter table users alter column user_id add generated by default as identity (start with %s);'
                           ,nextval('<current sequence name>')+100  -- some value above current 
                           );                       
begin
  alter table users alter column user_id drop default;
  raise notice '%', l_gen_start; 
  execute l_gen_start;
  drop sequence users_user_id_seq;
  commit; 
end; 
$$;
```